# What impact does upper/lower case have on SEO?

Tags: seo, content

*I am not asking about URL upper/lower cases.*

First lets look at these few examples.

Example 1:
`<p>Hi, My Name Is Imran Bughio!</p>`

Example 2:
`<p>HI, MY NAME IS IMRAN BUGHIO!</p>`

Example 3:
`<p style="text-transform:uppercase;">hi, my name is imran bughio!</p>`

**Question:** Does any of the above have any impact on SEO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to the URLs, there is no difference for SEO to use lowercase or uppercase for the `<p>` tag. As far as I know, search engines don't pay attention to it. The only case where it may have an impact (not sure), is for the acronyms.

However, you should write a sentence in the correct way (in respect of language rules; here the English) because all letters in lowercase or uppercase can be considered as spammy. In your case, the best sentence would be:

```
<p>Hi, my name is Imran Bughio!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have update my question based on your 2nd paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

It has absolutely no impact in terms of SEO with Google.

However if you put all words in the upper case, it is treated spammy by several spiders in search engines.

Truth be told, having it all in upper case is a much bigger disadvantage, but indenting your font well, will not do you any wonders, as far as SEO is concerned. It will certainly keep the visitors engaged and decrease your bounce rate, thereby commending the credibility of your article and helping SEO indirectly.

Answer (score -2):

In SEO let it be lowercase or Upper Case, all are considered as one as "TEXT" under `<p>` tag. Only bold letters on your page have some impact on your website performance.

It is not considered for SEO but automatically user experience is increased if you make bold for some specific keywords and phrases on your web pages.